# Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I'm working with THREE.js and glsl for shaders. I 'm trying to use this object for light:

```
function light(pos, color, intensity, rad){

      this.position = new THREE.Vector3(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z);
      this.clight = new THREE.Vector3(color.x,color.y,color.z);
      this.intensity = intensity;
      this.rad = rad;

    }

var light1 = new light(lightPosition,clight,inty,rad );
```

This is my uniform i want to pass:

```
var floorUniform = {
      baseColor: {type: "t", value: loadTexture(floorPath + "baseColor.png")},
      normalMap: {type: "t", value: loadTexture(floorPath + "normalMap.png")},
      roughnessMap: {type: "t", value: loadTexture(floorPath + "roughnessMap.png")},
      metalnessMap: {type: "t", value: loadTexture(floorPath + "metalness.png")},
      diffuseMap: {type: "t", value: loadTexture(floorPath + "diffuseMap.png")},
      normalScale: {type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2(1,1)},
      textureRepeat: {type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2(8,8)},
      light: light1,
      envMap: {type: "t", value: envMap},
      aoMap: {type: "t", value: loadTexture(floorPath + "AmbientOcclusionMap.png")}
    };
```

finally in fragment shaders this struct:

```
struct lightSource{
                vec3 position;
                vec3 clight;
                float intensity;
                float rad;
            };
uniform lightSource light;
```

So, when i attempt to read position attribute, the shaders throw error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

I can't figured out why, can someone help me?

Thanks in advice

Comment: what are the values for `lightPosition, clight, inty, rad` ?

Comment: // LIGHT 1
var lightPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0,20,0);
var clight =  new THREE.Vector3(1.0,0.71,0.02);
var inty = 1.0;
var rad = 20.0;

Comment: What you have provided so far is not sufficient to investigate the problem. Try to reproduce the error with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: @Gomi `light: light1` possibly should be like `light: {value: light1}`

Comment: @prisoner849 Thank you, it works! My bad, i'm still a beginner of js

Comment: You're welcome :)